# An establishment intellectual by affiliation

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of the words in bold?

**An establishment intellectual by affiliation**—he had served the Regime in
ministerial and cultural positions.

It is about an intellectual who was among the officials of the Regime.

---

Here is the [context](https://www.studydeed.com/samples-tbsmtx/9783319961187-txpl.pdf):

> The earliest flashes of the backlash against cultural alienation were sparked
>   by Seyyed Fakhruddin Shadman, a polymath from a traditional Shii family.
>   An **establishment intellectual by affiliation**—he had served the Pahlavis in
>   ministerial and cultural positions—Shadman took issue with the cultural
>   drift associated with modernization in the1940s.

Comment: The context makes things clearer. 'Establishment intellectual' means an intellectual who was [considered] one of the establishment. '... by affiliation' means 'because of the connections (with the establishment) he had'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a definition of *by* that this fits into ([Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/by)):

> 3.3 Identifying a parameter. ‘a breakdown of employment figures by age and occupation’

Here are some other examples:

> By birth, she was German, but she came to this country as a young child.
>
> He is a chemist by formal training, but his early publications are primarily in physics, and his true passion is mathematical biology.
>
> He is not a socialist or communist by party affiliation, but he is a self-avowed Marxist.

Now for your sentence:

> An establishment intellectual by affiliation—he had served the Pahlavis in ministerial and cultural positions—Shadman took issue with the cultural drift associated with modernization in the1940s.

Let's build up to this conclusion step by step.

Shadman had served the Pahlavis in ministerial and cultural positions.

So, by virtue of the service he had provided to the Pahlavis in his various positions as a government or cultural minister, you could describe him as an intellectual who fit into the cookie-cutter expectations of the establishment.  (Look up *establishment if you're not sure about that term.)

The above is his background.  Now, let's see what happens in the 1940's: He takes issue with, i.e., he objects to, the cultural drift associated with modernization.  (I don't know anything about this cultural drift -- hopefully you've read the whole thing and you do understand what they're talking about.)